# console.log() not outputting HTML of jQuery selection object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I got a problem when using `console.log` in Google Chrome. Suddenly when I was outputting a element like `$(this)` it was display like:

```
[<div>, context: <div>]
```

or

```
[jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]]
```

in the console. ( Both came from the same row: `console.log($(this))` )

This problem arose yesterday from nowhere. There ain't a problem with the code. I logged the exact same thing on an other computer and there it is being displayed like:

```
[<div class='element'></div>, ...]
```

**Update:** the new Chrome version changes the output of `console.log()`

Does anyone know how I can get back to the original settings of Google Chrome console?

Comment: I would recommend that you improve your acceppt rate and consider that even if there is no perfect answer each user that gave an answer is  trying to help and has put time and effort into their answer with the only benefit of getting points for an upvote or an accepted answer.

Comment: Please star https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162570

Answer (score 15):

To answer the question:

- Does anyone know how I can get back to the original settings of Google chrome console?

There are no settings to get the former output of console.log(). You can either:

- downgrade the browser (use an older version of chrome or [chromium based alternatives](http://www.howtogeek.com/108384/6-alternative-browsers-based-on-google-chrome/))
- overwrite `console.log()` by adding your own `function log()`
- use outerHTML in some cases or upgrade to chrome 25.0.1323.1 (dev channel) where console.log($(#Selector)[0]); returns outHMTL again (see below).

#### Chrome 23/24: Output of console.log() changed ***sometimes***

According to user916276 the output of console.log(jQuery-Object) has changed:

```
// output of console.log($jQuerObject) 
[<div class='element'></div>, ...] // in chrome <= 23
[<div>, context: <div>]            // in chrome 24
```

User [brentonstrine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925897/brentonstrine) made me aware of the fact that my context.outerHTML does not always work.

I updated my code with [a new example](http://jsfiddle.net/jXjb2/8/). It seems that the existence of `jqObject.context.outerHTML` depends how you pass the jQuery-Object to the function.
I tested it with [chrome dev channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) (25.0.1323.1) and two chromium based versions (21, 22).

```
console.log($(this)); // old chrome versions 
// new chrome version >23
// if you pass this to the function see my getThis(_this) function
console.log($(this).context.outerHTML); 
// if you use a jQuery selector
console.log($(this)[0]);   // at least in chrome build 25.0.1323.1
```

To avoid misunderstandings. This answer is about the changed behaviour of writing a jQuery object to the [inbuild console](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) of the recent  google chrome browsers (version 24, 25).

#### Chrome source code

I took a look into the chrome source code changes [at the Console.cpp](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/133614/trunk/Source/WebCore/page/Console.cpp) and in the [timeline view](http://trac.webkit.org/timeline?from=2012-11-06T08:14:27-08:00&precision=second) to find out about the changes in the [WebInspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector). I could not find the exact change that is responsible for the changed behaviour of `console.log()`. I assume that it has to do with [changes to ConsoleView.js](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/133150/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/ConsoleView.js), [2](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/127412/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/ConsoleView.js), [3](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/126709/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/ConsoleView.js).  If anyone would like to initiate that `console.log()` returns the same output as in Chrome 21, 22 he could file a bug. This [two](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101021) [bugs](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99941) could be used as a template to place the change request.

Comment: Yes I know, but $(this) shall not be displayed as I described above. $(this) shall contain an array of elements, not "context" and so on. If I outputs $(this) it shall be display as [<div class='element'></div>] not [<div>, context: <div>].

Comment: I updated the question. There´s no issue with to code, just the way chrome console displays it. As I mentioned above it worked yesterday and I works no if I'm using safari, or chrome on an other computer. Something has happened to the console in chrome.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Have you installed or updated any extensions  lately?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240523/console-log-messages-not-showing-up-in-chromes-javascript-console

Comment: The latest stable build. I got firebug lite and addblocker installed.

Comment: The cause of the problem is the latest version of Google Chrome that diplays $(this) like [<div>, context: <div>] instead of [<div></div>, ...]. I prefer the old one...

Comment: Must be something with WebKit source, I use Luakit. This really sucks, this new input is absolutelly useless. Men I am so pissed! this renders webkit useless for any web development.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree that is weird. I'm on 24, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @brentonstrine you found something i can not explain yet. i will update  my answer above shortly.

Comment: I'm surprised this continues to be a problem in chrome.

Answer (score 11):

`console.log.apply(console, $(this));`

Comment: Or to make a function out of it:

    var domLog = function($obj){
        console.log.apply(console,$obj);
    }
    domLog( $("div.anything") );

Comment: brentonstrine's comment above doesn't quite work because of the way comments lose their line breaks. Try: `var domLog = function($obj){ console.log.apply(console,$obj); }; domLog( $("div") );`

Answer (score 6):

The output is correct as $(this) refers to jQuery selection object, not the underlying DOM object(s).

If you wish to output the raw DOM element(s), you can try the following:

```
 console.log( $( this ).get(0) ) 
 // Or just 
 console.log( this )
```

Or you can also do:

```
 console.log( $( this ).html() )
```

Comment: Yeah but in previous version it logged `[<div class="element"></div>, ...]` :P

Comment: Still not nice, previously in addition to having an array of dom objects, you could open them and close them.

Comment: I don't really believe in this. The output is completely different. `console.log( $( this ).html() );` gives you plain text and `console.log( $( this ).get(0) );` gives you the HTML. **But** in case the object got siblings: (you can test that yourself) if you append `.attr( 'id' )`, you'll get nothing for the first one and an error for the later one. The Error is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [HTML HERE] has no property 'attr'`.

Comment: I didn't get attr() part at all

Answer (score 5):

Here is an even better solution than `console.log.apply(console, obj);` that I just discovered. Check out `console.dirxml(obj);` which gives nearly the same output when `obj` is a jQuery selector result set. However, only the latter works when `obj` is a specific element from a jQuery selector result set.

Here is a demo you can do on this page...

```
var i=0
console.log(++i);
console.dirxml($$('.answer'));
console.log(++i);
console.dirxml($$('.answer')[0]);
console.log(++i);
console.log.apply(console, $$('.answer'));
console.log(++i);
console.log.apply(console, $$('.answer')[0]);
```

You'll see that #4 logs "undefined".

[image: Performed at the console on this very page.]

So, from now on I'm going to use `console.dirxml` because it's simple, effective, and built in. Having to pass `console` as the first argument to `apply` never sat right with me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

By default , chrome now returns an object with all details pertaining to that element when u do a console.log($(element)).

an example of what it actually returns

```
  console.log($('input:first'));
  [<input>, prevObject: c.fn.c.init[1], context: #document, selector: "input:first"] 
  0: <input>
  context: #document
  length: 1
  prevObject: c.fn.c.init[1]
  selector: "input:first"
  __proto__: Object[0]
```

so if u do  console.log($('input:first')[0]) u would get ur desired Result.

hope this helps

Comment: In previous versions logging a jQuery object would display an array with the html representation of each of the objects.

Comment: This is the correct answer. putting `[0]` mimics the old behavior.

Comment: I will repeat my previous comment, as everyone seems to think appending `[0]` to your jQuery selector will give you the old output, it will not: $(this)[0] does only give you "old output" correctly if you only find one element, if you find many different elements, you will see it outputs only the first[0] in the array of elements, and thus is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

My edit to @brentonstrine's answer got rejected, so I'm going to make a new answer for it. But see [my other answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15802584/117471) for an **even better solution**.

This demo shows you why we care about logging this new way versus the normal way...

```
// paste this whole block into the console of THIS PAGE and see a working demo!

var domlog = function(obj){ console.log.apply(console, obj); };

domlog($('#answer-13594327'));

// compare ^that^ to the normal element logging...

var normallog = function(obj){ console.log(obj); };

normallog($('#answer-13594327'));
```

[image: Demo of the 2 different loggin metods]

Comment: In case my edit suggestions will not make it through (2 reject vs. 2 approve)

If `domlog($(id))` is used it returns the domnode in a way that you can mouse over it in the console and the matching node `<div id="answer-13594327">...</div>` is highligthed in its page context (see screenshot).

The function `normallog($(id))` returns the  [node] in brackets - mouse over does not highlight the bracketed node `[<div id="answer-13594327">...</div>]`

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log.apply(console, [].slice.call($('p'), 0))
-> ►<p>…</p>, ►<p>…</p>, <p class="label-key">viewed</p>
```

**Update:** [Simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268015/console-log-not-outputting-html-of-jquery-selection-object/13594327#13594327).

---

Rationale behind the console output change:

> What was the rationale behind the request to not include
>   attributes/textContent?

Response from pfeldman, DevTools developer:

> people that dump DOM lists appreciate the dense look.

[crbug.com/50316](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316#c37)

Comment: I see you beat me here with almost the same solution that I posted. What does the additional `[].slice.call(x,0)` that is in yours but not mine do?

Comment: It’s a common way to convert an array-like object to a real array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929924/how-to-sort-a-javascript-object-or-convert-it-to-an-array

Comment: [].slice.call doesn’t do anything here to the output of the console, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sollution, to wrap console.log in my own function, it has some shortcomings, like it doesn't tell you the line number the problem occured in but I make up by outputing significan log messages... if anyone want to improve on it feel free!

Note: `underscore.js` is a dependency, I'm sure you can do it in pure JS, but I always depend on underscore.js :)

```
// wrap the console.log function
var log = function(data) {
    // switch setting
    var allowed = true;
    if (allowed) {
        console.log("LOG");
        console.log(typeof data);
        if (typeof data == "object" || typeof data == "array") {
            _.each(data, function(item) {
                console.log(item);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    };
```

The take home message here is:

```
if (typeof data == "object" || typeof data == "array") {
            _.each(data, function(item) {
                console.log(item);
            });
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
```

Then you just do: `log($(".some.class"));` and get the elements as `old school` DOM objects in the console.