# Why Google Chrome has different console.log() output via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, console.log

When I console log a jquery object eg.

```
var s = $("#item");
console.log(s);
```

I get something like this

```
[div#item, context: document, selector: "#item", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

I remember before ( one month ago or so ), I would get something like:

```
 [<div id="item">pas</div>]
```

Is this change in Chrome itself? Or there was a change in jquery? Or I actually did something to make output look differently

I find this second output much easier to read and I can hover over this and have it marked on page. Now I get too much infos it's quite hard to read

Comment: *Seems* to be jQuery: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9prm9/); though now I think about it, it's possibly just a difference in the way Chrome logs Objects, rather than DOM nodes/elements.

Comment: yes looks like it works differently with plain javascript. Thanks for this, really useful

Comment: I tried changing the jQuery version in the fiddle, it didn't change the output significantly (the main difference is that the jQuery object didn't have a `jquery: <version#>` property before 1.9). I think the difference the OP may be thinking of is between evaluating a jQuery object in the console and using `console.log`.

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/EfKjH) (note — may have to refresh the page to get console output to show up correctly) is a codepen with $ versions 1.10.1, 1.9.0, and 1.8.3. Output is identical except for the jQuery version number as @Barmar says. There must be something else going in in the OP's case (perhaps a Chrome update).

Comment: possible duplicate of [console.log() not outputting HTML of jQuery selection object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268015/console-log-not-outputting-html-of-jquery-selection-object)

Comment: You cant print Jquery Object. it is not a string. in order to print $("#item") stored text you can use console.log($("#item").text())

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're noticing is the difference between evaluating a jQuery object in the console and displaying it with `console.log()`. Using David Thomas's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9prm9/), set a breakpoint on the `console.log` statement. When it stops at the breakpoint, type `$s` into the console and you'll see

```
[<div id="item">pas</div>]
```

Then continue, and you'll see the verbose object printed by `console.log()`.

I'm not really sure what jQuery or Chrome is doing that causes this difference. The output when you type `$s` seems to be the result of `$s.toArray()`, while `console.log()` shows the real jQuery object.

More proof that this isn't new behavior -- I just linked a duplicate question from November.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
var s = $("<div>").append($("#item").clone()).html();

console.log(s);

$(s).remove();
```

It's not in its prettiest form but the result is what you're looking for and I'm sure you could come up with a good function for it...

Basically I'm creating a div, putting a copy of #item into it, and spewing the div's innerHTML out to the console in order to show the entire #item element. (Not just #item's innerHTML)
Then I destroy s to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there may be a change with jquery, check how they are now dealing with dom objects in version `1.9.1`

http://jsfiddle.net/5HJ3L/1/

if you try the `console.log` in this manner

```
var s = $("#item");
console.log(s);
```

the output will be like

```
[div#item, context: document, selector: "#item", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
0: div#item
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#item"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

if you check it closely you will find the required output in the above array at key `0`, so the output for the following line will be

```
console.log(s[0]);
```

Output:

```
<div id="item">pas</div>
```

also if you try it without jquery the output will be the one you are required

```
var e = document.getElementById('item');
console.log(e);
```

Output:

```
<div id="item">pas</div>
```

**PS:** this is not a suggestion against jquery but to show how they will be deal by `google-chrome`

**Correction:** Also note that output mention in the question is in `array` form whereas the ways I have suggested is in `string`

Answer (score 1):

You can control the output style of a console log output  with c style console.log: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css

For example, to out put with a simple dom element style:

```
console.log("%o", document.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = $("#item").html();
console.log(s)
```

Comment: this will give you `pas` not `[<div id="item">pas</div>]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974740/how-do-i-console-log-a-jquery-dom-element-in-chrome

Comment: i hope this is help full

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected result for the console sending the DOM element and not the jquery.

```
console.log($("div")[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    if div value printed on div .. then plz menstion html(). 

    var s = $("#item").html();

    console.log(s);
```