# jQuery $(event.target) returns DOM in console, not HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

With this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.docs-tag', function(event){
    console.log($(event.target))
})
```

I expect to see:

```
[<some html>]
```

but instead get:

> [span.icon-tag docs-tag child_hover dropdown-open, context: span.icon-tag docs-tag child_hover dropdown-open, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.8.2"…]

I have recently upgraded to jQuery 1.8.2. Has there been a change in how `$(event.target)` is handled?

Comment: It's just how the DOM element (or jQuery object) is displayed in the console. No need to worry about it.

Comment: if the element has an attribute 'data-thing'='some value', then doing $(event.target).data('thing') returns undefined.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FxQJk/. But I use 1.8.3 in the fiddle, if it makes a difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [console.log() not outputting HTML of jQuery selection object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268015/console-log-not-outputting-html-of-jquery-selection-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with changes in the browser output, it doesn't have to do with jQuery. Here's a thread on the subject - [console.logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268015/console-log-not-outputting-html-of-jquery-selection-object).

Comment: Good find. Voting to close as duplicate (at least I think it is).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the DOM node, do this:

```
console.log($(event.target)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

event.target returns the DOM element, so you can retrieve any property/ attribute that has a value

try this

```
$(event.target).text()
```