# Javascript console.log not working inside function in debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

To debug some concepts I run this in Chrome Console:

```js
what = function(){ 
    let value = 5
    try { 
        wrong(); 
    } catch(e) { 
        console.log('bad'); 
        value += 1
    }
    return value
}
what()
# returns 6
```

Works as expected, except `console.log('bad')` never happens.

obviously the fact that value = 6 and not 5 is proof that block is called.

Why does console.log just get skipped in the console?  I'm pretty sure I've injected JS into apps where the console.log works so this is probably a setting in the console window itself.  Firefox's behavior is the same.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: How confident are you that you aren't filtering the console output view somehow?

Comment: How to break console.log -> `window.console.log = () => {}` - got anything like that?

Comment: @AlexanderNied in retrospect, zero % :( - someone pointed that out.  Sorry to ask such a bone-headed question

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, since it isn't working on either platform, is that it is an extension that is blocking it -- from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240523/console-log-messages-not-showing-up-in-chromes-javascript-console), it may be firebug lite or you accidentally disabled it through your filters.

If none of this works, I suggest trying out a guest window and seeing if it works there.

I can not reproduce this on my own machine as well as others: Chrome 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 102_win_control)

Comment: Yes it was as simple as disabling it with the filter which I didn't notice.  Sorry to make a post like this when the problem was indeed that obvious

Answer (score 0):

It is working! **Remove the last line** and it will work! If it again did not worked then it is might blocking by an extension

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).